# How to change both header text and tab text in React-Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested stack navigator within a tab navigator like so:

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  BookmarksList: createStackNavigator({
    BookmarkList: { screen: BookmarkList },
    UpdateBookmark: { screen: UpdateForm }
  }),
  NewBookmark: createStackNavigator({
    NewBookmark: { screen: NewBookmarkScreen }
  })
});
```

When I set navigationOptions title text for `BookmarkList`, it only changes the header text, but not the tab text.

For example, I've set my `BookmarkList` title to `My Bookmarks`.

```
class BookmarkList extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'My Bookmarks'
  };    
}
```

This gets reflected in the header text, but not in the tab text, which still says `BookmarkList` (circled in red):

[image]

How do I get both header and tab text to change to the same text?

**tldr;** Customising title via navigationOptions only changes header text, but not tab text in nested stack navigator within tab navigator. How to change both header and tab text?

Comment: To change tab text use `tabBarLabel` in TabNavigator's `navigationOptions`. See [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbarlabel) for reference

Answer (score 5):

One solution:

```
    const BookmarksList = createStackNavigator({
      BookmarkList: { screen: BookmarkList },
      UpdateBookmark: { screen: UpdateForm },
    });

    const NewBookmark = createStackNavigator({
      NewBookmark: { screen: NewBookmarkScreen },
    });

    const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      BookmarksList: {
        screen: BookmarksList,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'My Bookmarks',
        },
      },
      NewBookmark: {
        screen: NewBookmark,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'New Bookmarks',
        },
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I had two duplicate headers with the solution of @aciobanita, because I have a parent AppContainer, it is necessary to deactivate the header of the parent and then use the solution of @aciobanita, its works for me without problem

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainApplication: { 
      screen: MainApplication,
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Child component:

```
    const BookmarksList = createStackNavigator({
      BookmarkList: { screen: BookmarkList },
      UpdateBookmark: { screen: UpdateForm },
    });

    const NewBookmark = createStackNavigator({
      NewBookmark: { screen: NewBookmarkScreen },
    });

    const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      BookmarksList: {
        screen: BookmarksList,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'My Bookmarks',
        },
      },
      NewBookmark: {
        screen: NewBookmark,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: 'New Bookmarks',
        },
      },
    });


export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```